# Llamar a procedimiento almacenado en PostgreSQL con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en PostgreSQL, el cual retorna algunos registros en base a unos cálculos y consultas, la tabla de retorno es la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Laravel lo llamo de la siguiente forma

```
  DB::beginTransaction();

                    $results=DB::select('SELECT kardex_consulta_articulo(?,?,?)',
                                [$input['producto_id'],
                                $input['finicio'],
                                $input['ffin'],
                            ]);

                    $valor_retorno =$results[0]->kardex_consulta_articulo;
                DB::commit();
```

Al hacerlo retorna algo de esta forma. Pero al probar en `postman`, da esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer que devuelva las columnas como la primera imagen? Es decir sin el nombre de la unión y los campos separados por coma.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta llamando a esa función de este modo

```
SELECT * FROM kardex_consulta_articulo...
```

en tu código la estás llamando así:

```
SELECT kardex_consulta_articulo...
```

Comment: Gracias funciono, yo usaba de la otra forma para recibir parametros de retorno. Saludos